# Is There a Way To Keep Precision When Transforming GameObjects

Tags: unity, c#

I've seen this issue before, but it's never been a particular issue for me until today.  I have each "room" of a dungeon created with a class script that contains details of that room.  During the process of building the dungeon, rooms may be mirrored or rotated.  When I rotate the y-axis, it updates properly the first time, going from `0` to `180`, but if I mirror it back and forth, it begins to get very small variances away from true `0` and `180`.  Over time, this could impact some things.  The code I'm using to do this is:

```
    public void RoomMirror()
    {
        transform.Rotate(0, (transform.localRotation.y==180) ? 0.0000f : 180.0000f, 0);
        Mirror = !Mirror;
        Swap(ref _east, ref _west);
    }
```

I added the four places in the float to try to overcome this issue, but it doesn't seem to be making any difference.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a common rule you should always rebuild that kind of matrix instead of repeatedly applying transforms, or you get the kind of cumulative error you're seeing =)  Every new transform and the error gets worse and worse, faster and faster.

This is because floating point numbers are imprecise and a matrix has many multiplications applied to it at each new transform.  You suspected this already because of adding the 4 places to the float (which didn't do anything for you here).

How floats work is a tidy little subject to read up on, you can get through several sources both within and without game development in an evening.

Comment: What would be the method to rebuild the transform? I thought that by setting it rather than modifying it.

Comment: To clarify: That transform.Rotate() does not set or reset anything directly, it takes the current contents of transform and applies the rotation math to it.  The next time RoomMirror() is called that same transform variable is again multiplied with .Rotate().  At this point I think that you should review the 3D math API that you're using and what floating point inaccuracy is.  You may also have some confusion on how "transform" is declared, set and used, and the API will help you know how to reset it so new transformations can be applied without accumulating these errors.

Comment: No, I get the inaccuracy regarding floats. But I was indeed misunderstanding .Rotate(). I've worked around it for now and may just extend things to work better with my logic.

Answer (score -1):

```
    public void RoomMirror()
    {
        Vector3 temp = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
        if (temp.y == 0f)
        {
            temp.y = 180.0f;
        }
        else 
        {
            temp.y = 0.0f;
        }
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(temp);
        Mirror = !Mirror;
        RoomMirror(ref _east, ref _west);
    }
```

This seems to have resolved the issue, though I'm not sure it's the best approach.  I may mark this as an answer at some point, unless someone can show me an error in logic or a way to do this that would be cleaner.